# Ruby match elements from the first with second array

Tags: arrays, ruby, comparison

I have two arrays. The first one will be an array of string with a name and the amount. The second is an array of letters.

```
a1 = ["ASLK 50", "BSKD 150", "ZZZZ 100", "BSDF 50"]
a2 = ["B", "Z"]
```

I want to create a third array to sort the contents from a1 based off a2 and return the number based on the information from first array. Since a2 has "B" and "Z", I need to scan first array for all entry starting with letter B and Z and add up the numbers.

My ultimate goal is to return the sum on third array, something like this:

```
a3 = ["B = 200", "Z = 100"]
```

Since "A" was not on a2, it is not counted.

I was able to extract the information from a1:

```
arr = a1.map{|el| el[0] + " : " + el.gsub(/\D/, '\1')}
#=> ["A : 50", "B : 150", "Z : 100", "B : 50"]
```

I am having trouble comparing a1with a2. I have tried different methods, such as:

```
a1.find_all{|i| i[0] == a2[0]} #=> only returns the first element of a2. How can I iterate through a2?
```

alternatively,

```
i = 0
arr_result = []
while i < (arr.length + 1)
    #(append to arr_result the number from  a1 if a1[i][0] matches a2[i])
```

I think either would solve it, but I can't put neither idea down to working code. How can I implement either method? Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running with your requirements, that you want to turn this:

```
a1 = ["ASLK 50", "BSKD 150", "ZZZZ 100", "BSDF 50"]
a2 = ["B", "Z"]
```

into this: `a3 = ["B = 200", "Z = 100"]`

```
a3 = a2.map do |char|
  sum = a1.reduce(0) do |sum, item|
    name, price = item.split(" ")
    sum += price.to_i if name[0].eql?(char)
    sum
  end
  "#{char} = #{sum}"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do this:

```
a1 = ["ASLK 50", "BSKD 150", "ZZZZ 100", "BSDF 50"]
a2 = ["B", "Z"]
a3 = a1.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |a,obj|
  obj[a[0]] += a.split.last.to_i if a2.include?(a[0]) 
end.map {|a| a.join(" = ")}
#=>["B = 200", "Z = 100"]
```

First step adds them all into a `Hash` by summing the values by each first letter that is contained in the second Array.

Second step provides the desired output

If you want a Hash instead just take off the last call to map and you'll have.

```
{"B" => 200, "Z" => 100}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than defining an `Array` like `["B = 200", "Z = 100"]`, it would be more sensible to define this as a *mapping* - i.e. the following `Hash` object:

```
{"B" => 200, "Z" => 100}
```

As for the implementation, there are many ways to do it. Here is just one approach:

```
a1 = ["ASLK 50", "BSKD 150", "ZZZZ 100", "BSDF 50"]
a2 = ["B", "Z"]
result = a2.map do |letter|
  [
    letter,
    a1.select {|str| str[0] == letter}
      .inject(0) {|sum, str| sum += str[/\d+/].to_i}
  ]
end.to_h

puts result # => {"B"=>200, "Z"=>100}
```

Explanation:

- At the top level, I've used [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-to_h) to convert the array of pairs: `[["B", 200], ["Z", 100]]` into a `Hash`: `{"B" => 200, "Z" => 100}`.
- `a1.select {|str| str[0] == letter}` selects only the elements from `a1` whose first letter is that of the hash key.
- `inject(0) {|sum, str| sum += str[/\d+/].to_i}` adds up all the numbers, with safe-guards to default to zero (rather than having `nil` thrown around unexpectedly).

Comment: I didn't think of using hash. This is a great idea!! If I didn't ask to return for an array specifically, I would have gone with this. I will keep this in mind!

Answer (score 1):

This is quite similar to @engineersmnky's answer.

```
r = /
    \A[A-Z] # match an upper case letter at the beginning of the string
    |       # or
    \d+     # match one or more digits
    /x      # free-spacing regex definition mode

a1.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |s,h|
  start_letter, value = s.scan(r)
  h[start_letter] += value.to_i if a2.include?(start_letter)
end.map { |k,v| "#{k} = #{v}" }
  #=> ["B = 200", "Z = 100"]
```

`Hash.new(0)` is often referred to as a "counting hash". See the doc for the class method [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) for an explanation.

The regex matches the first letter of the string or one or more digits. For example,

```
"ASLK 50".scan(r)
  #=> ["A", "50"]
```

Comment: I like the regex implementation nice work Cary but `.map { |k,v| "#{k} = #{v}" % [k,v] }` seems like it should be `.map { |k,v| "%s = %d" % [k,v] }` if we are using format or `.map { |k,v| "#{k} = #{v}"}` to just use interpolation because right now you are interpolating and then formatting nothing. The only way this would work is something like `k2 = %s; v2 = %d; "#{k2} = #{v2}" % [k,v]` because the interpolation will occur prior to formatting.

Comment: @engineersmnky, thanks for pointing that out. I changed the formatting from `%` to `#{...}` midstream and neglected to remove  `% [k,v]`. Fixed it.